# Hadoop job keeps running and no container is allocated

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs, hadoop-yarn

I tried running a mapreduce job in Hadoop 2.8.5 but it keeps running.
The Application State is as below:
`YarnApplicationState:    ACCEPTED: waiting for AM container to be allocated, launched and register with RM.`

RM web UI:
[image]

The health-report says: 1/1 local-dirs are bad: /home/hduser/hadooptmpdata/nm-local-dir; 1/1 log-dirs are bad: /home/hduser/hadoop-2.8.5/logs/userlogs

[image]

**core-site.xml**

```
<configuration>
<property>
<name>fs.defaultFS</name>
<value>hdfs://localhost:9000</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name>
<value>/home/hduser/hadooptmpdata</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

**hdfs-site.xml**

```
<configuration>
<property>
<name>dfs.replication</name>
<value>1</value>
<name>dfs.name.dir</name>
<value>file:///home/hduser/hdfs/namenode</value>
<name>dfs.data.dir</name>
<value>file:///home/hduser/hdfs/datanode</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

**yarn-site.xml**

```
<configuration>
<property>
<name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
<value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
</property>

<property>
<name>yarn.scheduler.capacity.maximum-am-resource-percent</name>
<value>100</value>
</property>

<property>
<name>yarn.nodemanager.resource.cpu-vcores</name>
<value>3</value>
</property>     

<property>
<name>yarn.scheduler.minimum-allocation-vcores</name>
<value>1</value>
</property>

<property>
<name>yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-vcores</name>
<value>3</value>
</property>

<property>
<name>yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb</name>
<value>4096</value>
</property>

<property>
<name>yarn.scheduler.minimum-allocation-mb</name>
<value>2048</value>
</property>

<property>
<name>yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-mb</name>
<value>4096</value>
</property>

<property>
<name>yarn.nodemanager.local-dirs</name>
<value>/home/hduser/hadooptmpdata/nm-local-dir</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

**mapred-site.xml**

```
<configuration>
<property>
<name>mapreduce.framework.name</name>
<value>yarn</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>mapreduce.map.memory.mb</name>
<value>2048</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>mapreduce.map.cpu.vcores</name>
<value>2</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>mapreduce.reduce.memory.mb</name>
<value>2048</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>mapreduce.reduce.cpu.vcores</name>
<value>2</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>mapreduce.cluster.local.dir</name>
<value>/home/user/hduser/hadooptmpdata/mapred/local</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

I am running Hadoop on **ubuntu** and my pc have **intel i7 processor** with **16 gb RAM** and **256 GB SSD**

Comment: You need to allocate some resources (memory and vcores) to YARN, https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r3.1.1/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-common/yarn-default.xml

Answer (score 2):

YARN's Resource Manager need compute resources from Node Manager(s) in order to run anything.  Your Node Manager shows it's local directory is bad.  Which means you have no compute resources available (which is verified looking at your cluster metrics.  See all the zeros.) which is why your application is stuck in "ACCEPTED".

[image]

Fix your `yarn.nodemanager.local-dirs` and make sure YARN has full permissions on it to proceed.

Comment: Sir i changed my yarn-site.xml and mapred-site.xml (you can see those updated files above). But nothing changed a lot. Still it says local dirs are bad. Can you please recommend something?

Comment: Did you try changing it to something completely new to make sure your permissions are correct?

Comment: All permissions are correct. I manually checked it. When I configured hadoop on my second laptop, everything worked completely fine.